# How to query params in nested attributes writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my nested attributes writer some of my attributes have id's and some don't:

```
attributes => [{"id"=>23, "name"=>"John Doe"}, {"name"=>"Jane Doe"}]
```

I want destroy an object unless its id is included in the attributes array. I don't know how to properly query the attributes, so am doing it like this for now:

```
id_array = attributes.collect{|a| a[:id]}
object.destroy unless id_array.include(object.id)
```

I'd prefer to avoid creating the id_array and instead accomplish it in one line to match this pseudocode:

```
object.destroy UNLESS THERE'S AN ATTRIBUTE ELEMENT WITH SAME ID
```

Having trouble coming up with a query that works on attributes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
attributes.reject!{ |elem| !elem["id"] }
```

EDIT:

```
object.destroy unless attributes.collect{|elem| elem["id"]}.include?(object.id)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how that helps because all it does it return an array that filters out objects without id's (as opposed to my 1st line which creates a new array consisting solely of object id's from the original array. In either case a second line is required to query the new/modifed array to see if the object in question's id matches any that are present in the array. What I'm hoping is to create a single query for the attributes array that tells me if it contains an object with a specific id.

Comment: Thanks. I tried chaining before asking here, but must have missed something in my earlier attempts. Appreciate the help!